# join two columns with same title but in different table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `pur` with values as

```
CUST_ID AMOUNT 
1    100                                   
3     50                                   
1    200                                   
1    500
3     20
```

and table `cus` with values as:

```
CUST_ID
1
2
3
```

How do I get to show this:

```
 CUST_ID   Total_AMOUNT
 2          0
 3          70
 1          800
```

Simply put, how do I show 2 columns from `cus` table?

Comment: RTM: [`join` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) and [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and then get `SUM` of the `AMOUNT` by grouping rows with the same `CUST_ID` :

```
SELECT t2.CUST_ID
     , COALESCE(SUM(t1.AMOUNT), 0) AS TOTAL
FROM cus t2 LEFT JOIN pur t1 ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
GROUP BY  t2.CUST_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/719be/8)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked but can't figure out why the value against 2 shows NULL when I had already defined amount to be NOT NULL

Comment: @user3764208 : As you use `LEFT JOIN`, values, that are not present in the right (`CUST_ID` = `2`) table are replaced with `NULL`. Then you are trying to `SUM(NULL)` and it ends with `NULL` value in the `AMOUNT` column. As you can see in my answer, you can easily check it and replace with `0`,using `COALESCE` , `CASE`, `IF` and etc.